# Java : Parsing Long throws error

Tags: java, mongodb, casting

I am using MongoDb. I have a collection named 'counter'. I am trying to retrieve a value of the field 'seq', which is stored as double inside the MongoDb.

First the value of the 'seq' field is increment by 1, which works fine. If I end up printing the value of the seq just after converting it to the string it works fine. It returns a string value.

However when I try to parse the String value such as 1.0 to Long using the Long.parseLong() or Long.valueOf() function, it throws an error.

> SEVERE: The RuntimeException could not be mapped to a response,
>   re-throwing to the HTTP container java.lang.NumberFormatException: For
>   input string: "47.0"

```
public long getNextSeq(){
        DBCollection coll = getCollection(getDb(DB_NAME), "counters");
        coll.update(new BasicDBObject().append("_id","blogId"), new BasicDBObject().append("$inc",new BasicDBObject("seq",1)));
        DBObject seqObj = coll.findOne();
        String seqStr = seqObj.get("seq").toString();
        long seq = Long.valueOf(seqStr);
        return seq;
}
```

So I would like to know why I can't convert that 47.0 to long, and what is the solution.

Note: 
`seqObj.get("seq")` would produce BSONObject. (MongoDb query)

Comment: Have you tried `DBObject seqObj = coll.findOne();
long seq = seqObj.getLong("seq");`?

Comment: @chridam I don't think you can use long seq = seqObj.getLong("seq"). getLong() doesn't exist.

Comment: Refer to the [documentation](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.8.0/org/bson/BasicBSONObject.html#getLong(java.lang.String)). Have you tried it?

Comment: @chridam  seqObject is DBObject and and after trying seqObj.get("seq").getLong() it shows me error.I imported library as well.  And also when I try to do something like  BSONObject bs = seqObj.get("seq") it asks me to typecast it to BSONObject, However when I use seqObj.get("seq") in eclipse the popup shows that it would return BSONObject.

Comment: You are trying to do `seqObj.get("seq").getLong()` instead of `long seq = seqObj.getLong("seq")`

Comment: @chridam: I know. seqObj is of DBObject type. NOT BSONObject type. When you do seqObj.get("seq") then only you would get BSONObject and hence then only you could use that getLong function on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually do the following:

```
long l = ((Number) seqObj.get("seq")).longValue();
```

Comment: Want a long value. Not double. You can convert it into long later on. But why perform that many conversion, first to string then to double and then to long.

Comment: Updated to get a long. I don't do any string conversions